# What are the best strategies/practices for Rails upgradation from 2.3.11 to 4.0.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, dependencies, upgrade, strategy-pattern

I would like to upgrade one of my application from rails -2.3.11 to 4.0.0. 
      Before going to do anything, I just need plan for it and my application not that
      much of big size but got some 6/7 plugins and 5/6 gems.

```
  Existed    : Ruby 1.8.7 + Rails 2.3.11
  Expected : Ruby 2.0.0 + Rails 4.0.0

   For this, I have plan as in two ways like below,
   1).Multi-step process : First need to upgrade app from rails 2.* to 3.* and then
      do upgrade from rails 3.* to 4.0.0
   2).Create new application from rails - 4.0.0 and rebuild old application all 
      features as we have already css, layouts...


   I hope both strategies will take same time.

 Any how, I need some inputs from you all. So please share your thoughts/comments.

     Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you could upgrade your Ruby gradually to 2.1.1. Then start to upgrade your Rails app from 2 to 3, finally upgrade to 4. If you have good test coverage, you could make sure that you did not break anything. Rewrite is also an option. I recommend you read this article [A Guide for Upgrading Ruby on Rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html).

Comment: I would be (hugely) astonished if rails 2.3.1 ran on ruby 2.1.1. I would probably start with migrating to the latest version of rails 2.3 (probably 15? long time since) and then migrate to ruby 1.9.2 before moving to rails 3. The move to rails 3 is the most time consuming in my experience. Without knowledge of the application it is hard to tell if this will take more time than rewriting it. Even in rails 4 you would be able to reuse most of your view and CSS code (though the switch to SCSS will pay of in the long run).

Comment: Ah yes. My idea is upgrade Ruby is easier. Upgrade Ruby first, then upgrade Rails. The html & css is fine. I think along the way you would encounter a lot of deprecation & removed feature that you need to change in your model & controller & route.

Answer (score 0):

check these casts ,it will help you migrating from rails 2 to rails 3 and then from rails 3 to rails 4
they are very helpfull

http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/226-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-2

http://railscasts.com/episodes/227-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-3

and then upgrading to rails 4

http://railscasts.com/episodes/415-upgrading-to-rails-4